# Seperate string after character space into var1 & var2 using Python

Tags: python, string

I was wondering how I could edit the string `'ABCDE foox123'` into two variables, `var1` being `'ABCDE'` and `var2` being `'foox123'`, so it seperates the string after the space into the two variables `var1` & `var2`.

Comment: What have you tried? A quick search of "split string on space python" on Google will yield just what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split, then do a destructuring assigment:

```
var1, var2 = "ABCDE foox123".split(' ')
```

Comment: You also do not need space `' '` while doing split. It by default splits on white space. Just do `.split()`

Comment: Good to note, but I think it makes more sense to spell it out here.